# How to compare two strings word by word in java

Tags: java, android

My code:

```
String[] EtChArray = etValue.split("");
String[] VtChArray = fullStory.split("");

if (EtChArray[i].isEmpty()) {
   i++;
} else {
   if (EtChArray[i].equals(VtChArray[i])) {
       tview1.setText(EtChArray[i]);
       tview1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
       i++;
   } else {
       tview1.setText(EtChArray[i]);
       tview1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       i++;

   }
}
```

I want to compare "edit text" with "viewtext" in android studio (java). I want to enter text in the edit text box and compare it in real time with viewtext (predefined text) character after character but I get problem at compating spaces.

Comment: you are splitting string using empty string (""). I guess, it should be, `etValue.split(" ")` and `fullStory.split(" ")` .

Comment: `String.split(String)` takes a regex(*regular expression*). The regex for one or more consecutive white-spaces is `\s+`. In Java, you have to escape the ``\``, so you would write `String[] EtChArray = etValue.split("\\s+");` and `String[] VtChArray = fullStory.split("\\s+");`

Comment: If you have leading (and or trailing) whitespace, `trim()` before you `split()`.

Comment: Suppose: 

   s1="Hello world I am showkat" ;
   s2= "Hello world I was busy" ;
Now how to compare the two strings word by word

Comment: I am working on an app in android. I have one edit text box and one view text box. I want to enter text in edit text box and compare it with text view text in real time and highlight the word errors if any

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s1 = "Hello world I am showkat";
    String s2 = "Hello world I was busy";

    String s1_words[] = s1.split("\\s");
    String s2_words[] = s2.split("\\s");

    int num_words = s1_words.length;

    if (num_words == s2_words.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
            System.out.print("word " + (i+1) + ": " + s1_words[i].equals(s2_words[i]) + "\n");
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
word 1: true

word 2: true

word 3: true

word 4: false

word 5: false
```

Comment: if(mEdit.length() > 0){
           
                if(mEdit.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(tvText.getText().toString().substring(0,mEdit.length()))){
                    tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }else{
                    tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } 
The above code changes the entire text color to Red when any of the typed word is incorrect. I want only the incorrect word to be colored red.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Text View for Comparison
    final TextView tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // Edit text View where you will type text
    final EditText tvEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    // Listener for checking change in text
    tvEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit)
        {
            if(mEdit.length() > 0){
                // Equals Ignore case if you dont want to check on the basis of case
                // This will check whether the typed string and your saved string upto that point match or not
                if(mEdit.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(tvText.getText().toString().substring(0,mEdit.length()))){
                    tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }else{
                    tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
}
```

Comment: if(mEdit.length() > 0){ if(mEdit.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(tvText.getText().toString().substring(0,mEdit.length()))){ tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); }else{ tvEdit.setTextColor(Color.RED); } The above code changes the entire text color to Red when any of the typed word is incorrect. I want only the incorrect word to be colored red.